# Remove image tag from all li tags that has no ul tag

Tags: jquery

I am creating a sliding menu where I have queried the database to create ul and li tag like this

```
sb.Append("<li><img/><a target='_blank' href='" + s.URL + "' >" + s.Text + "</a>");
                sb.Append(this.getChildren(s.ID));
                sb.Append("</li>");
```

Now I want to remove this image tag from all li tag which has no immediate ul or submenu.How to achieve that?

```
   $('#listContainer li img').click(function (e) {

            var checkElement = $(this).siblings('ul');   //new code

             find all li without any ul and remove img tag 

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Remove image tag from all li tags that has no ul tag*

You can use:

```
$('li:not(:has(ul)) img').remove();
```